# Emulator not working in Android Studio

Tags: emulator, intel-haxm, accelerator

I'm running Android Studio on Windows 1 64-bit system, and I keep getting the error:
"ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!"

I have installed the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator Installer (HAXM installer)
[Installed Accelerator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JebHg.png)

I have enabled Virtualization in BIOS.

I have confirmed that my processor (i7-5500U) is XD compatable.

But despite all of that I continue to get the emulator error: 
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbksW.png)

P.S New to app development but tried to search for solution.

Thanks for any help and guidance you can provide